# Wait until logout is done

Tags: angularjs, promise, routes, resolve

Controller in my default route gets executed after I logout. For loginG out I am just calling a server route using $http.post. As the thing is async, execution continues to go to my default route '\' but I don't want controller of my default route to execute until logout is complete. How can I create a link between logout and my controller? I know I can use promise to wait for Logout but this would be only in the function where I am calling logout. How can I wait in my controller for logout to finish?

Will appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: where do you call logout and redirect to default path?

Comment: I'm calling logout on a button and redirecting to '\login' page but for some reason it executes default '\' route as well but don't know why.

Comment: @Imad any feedback on my solution? Did it work? Did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Promises let you add a handler to their completion that's chainable:

```
// inside your controller action causing the log out:

$http.post("/logout").done(function(result){
   // here you're logged out, the promise has its value
   $location.href = "/"; // change route
});
```

Note: you can also wait in your router, but I assume from your question you'd like to avoid that.

Note2: I'd extract membership into a service.